# SQL help on Data Views for _SENT table

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, data-views

In creating an audience for a Journey, I'm pulling everyone who already received one of our Welcome emails so they skip that step in the Journey.  To do this, we've written the query below and it works for the most part.

```
SELECT 
SubscriberKey as EMAIL_ADDRESS_, 
   CASE WHEN EMAILID = '14146' then 'TRUE'
        WHEN EMAILID = '3661' then 'TRUE'
          ELSE 'FALSE' END
 as WelcomeSent
FROM _SENT s
JOIN _JOB j on S.JobID = J.JobID
WHERE 
SubscriberKey in (SELECT EMAIL_ADDRESS_ FROM [WELCOME])
```

The issue arises when someone received multiple emails (for example, a Welcome and an Abandoned Cart email) -- because a record appears multiple times in the **_SENT** table, the LAST email received will populate the value in **WelcomeSent**.

This means we get a few False-positives. That is, people who received the **WELCOME** but the data results shows as **FALSE**

**How do we modify the code such that only the WELCOME email is considered in the query?**

What complicates this further is that we have no idea if the **WELCOME** email was sent before or after other emails received by the subscriber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to filter the query to only pull those email ids instead of creating a case around it.

For example:

```
SELECT 
SubscriberKey as EMAIL_ADDRESS_, 
'TRUE' as WelcomeSent
FROM _SENT s
JOIN _JOB j on S.JobID = J.JobID
WHERE 
SubscriberKey in (SELECT EMAIL_ADDRESS_ FROM [WELCOME])
AND j.EMAILID IN ('14146','3661')
```

This will return only those from the SENT Dataview that are in the WELCOME DE and that have the EmailID of 14146 or 3661 inside of the JOB dataview. Which I believe is what your goal was.

Comment: and a default value of FALSE should take care of the rest -- THANK YOU!

Comment: My only comment is that I had to move the **EMAILID in** statement to before the **SELECT EMAIL_ADDRESS_ FROM WELCOME** statement